# Initial visualization of datasets in Scikit - head() command

Tags: python, r, pandas, sklearn-pandas

In considering the potential equivalence of Python to R for data processing, I am working on the basics. In particular, when loading a database, such as *Iris* in R, the simple command `head()` produces a beautiful printout on the screen:

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

[Scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) include this dataset, but if I weren't familiar with it, and was trying to just take a peek at what it looks like, these would be the first unfortunate results:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
iris
{'DESCR': 'Iris Plants Database\n\nNotes\n-----\nData Set Characteristics:\n    :Number of Instances: 150 (50 in each of three classes)\n    :Number of Attributes: 4 numeric, predictive attributes and the class\n    :Attribute Information:\n        - sepal length in cm\n        - sepal width in cm\n        - petal length in cm\n        - petal width in cm\n        - class:\n                - Iris-Setosa\n                - Iris-Versicolour\n                - Iris-Virginica\n    :Summary Statistics:\n\n    ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================\n                    Min  Max   Mean    SD   Class Correlation\n    ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================\n    sepal length:   4.3  7.9   5.84   0.83    0.7826\n    sepal width:    2.0  4.4   3.05   0.43   -0.4194\n    petal length:   1.0  6.9   3.76   1.76    0.9490  (high!)\n    petal width:    0.1  2.5   1.20  0.76     0.9565  (high!)\n    ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================\n\n    :Missing Attribute Values: None\n    :Class Distribution: 33.3% for each of 3 classes.\n    :Creator: R.A. Fisher\n    :Donor: Michael Marshall (MARSHALL%PLU@io.arc.nasa.gov)\n    :Date: July, 1988\n\nThis is a copy of UCI ML iris datasets.\nhttp://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris\n\nThe famous Iris database, first used by Sir R.A Fisher\n\nThis is perhaps the best known database to be found in the\npattern recognition literature.  Fisher\'s paper is a classic in the field and\nis referenced frequently to this day.  (See Duda & Hart, for example.)  The\ndata set contains 3 classes of 50 instances each, where each class refers to a\ntype of iris plant.  One class is linearly separable from the other 2; the\nlatter are NOT linearly separable from each other.\n\nReferences\n----------\n   - Fisher,R.A. "The use of multiple measurements in taxonomic problems"\n     Annual Eugenics, 7, Part II, 179-188 (1936); also in "Contributions to\n     Mathematical Statistics" (John Wiley, NY, 1950).\n   - Duda,R.O., & Hart,P.E. (1973) Pattern Classification and Scene Analysis.\n     (Q327.D83) John Wiley & Sons.  ISBN 0-471-22361-1.  See page 218.\n   - Dasarathy, B.V. (1980) "Nosing Around the Neighborhood: A New System\n     Structure and Classification Rule for Recognition in Partially Exposed\n     Environments".  IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine\n     Intelligence, Vol. PAMI-2, No. 1, 67-71.\n   - Gates, G.W. (1972) "The Reduced Nearest Neighbor Rule".  IEEE Transactions\n     on Information Theory, May 1972, 431-433.\n   - See also: 1988 MLC Proceedings, 54-64.  Cheeseman et al"s AUTOCLASS II\n     conceptual clustering system finds 3 classes in the data.\n   - Many, many more ...\n',
 'data': array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
        [ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2],
        [ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2],
        [ 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2],
        [ 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2],
        [ 5.4,  3.9,  1.7,  0.4],
        [ 4.6,  3.4,  1.4,  0.3],
        [ 5. ,  3.4,  1.5,  0.2],
        [ 4.4,  2.9,  1.4,  0.2],
        [ 4.9,  3.1,  1.5,  0.1],
        [ 5.4,  3.7,  1.5,  0.2],
        [ 4.8,  3.4,  1.6,  0.2],
        [ 4.8,  3. ,  1.4,  0.1],
        [ 4.3,  3. ,  1.1,  0.1],
        [ 5.8,  4. ,  1.2,  0.2],
        [ 5.7,  4.4,  1.5,  0.4],
        [ 5.4,  3.9,  1.3,  0.4],
        [ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.3],
        [ 5.7,  3.8,  1.7,  0.3],
        [ 5.1,  3.8,  1.5,  0.3],
        [ 5.4,  3.4,  1.7,  0.2],
        [ 5.1,  3.7,  1.5,  0.4],
        [ 4.6,  3.6,  1. ,  0.2],
        [ 5.1,  3.3,  1.7,  0.5],
        [ 4.8,  3.4,  1.9,  0.2],
        [ 5. ,  3. ,  1.6,  0.2],
        [ 5. ,  3.4,  1.6,  0.4],
        [ 5.2,  3.5,  1.5,  0.2],
        [ 5.2,  3.4,  1.4,  0.2],
        [ 4.7,  3.2,  1.6,  0.2],
        [ 4.8,  3.1,  1.6,  0.2],
        [ 5.4,  3.4,  1.5,  0.4],
        [ 5.2,  4.1,  1.5,  0.1],
        [ 5.5,  4.2,  1.4,  0.2],
        [ 4.9,  3.1,  1.5,  0.1],
        [ 5. ,  3.2,  1.2,  0.2],
        [ 5.5,  3.5,  1.3,  0.2],
        [ 4.9,  3.1,  1.5,  0.1],
        [ 4.4,  3. ,  1.3,  0.2],
        [ 5.1,  3.4,  1.5,  0.2],
        [ 5. ,  3.5,  1.3,  0.3],
        [ 4.5,  2.3,  1.3,  0.3],
        [ 4.4,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2],
        [ 5. ,  3.5,  1.6,  0.6],
        [ 5.1,  3.8,  1.9,  0.4],
        [ 4.8,  3. ,  1.4,  0.3],
        [ 5.1,  3.8,  1.6,  0.2],
        [ 4.6,  3.2,  1.4,  0.2],
        [ 5.3,  3.7,  1.5,  0.2],
        [ 5. ,  3.3,  1.4,  0.2],
        [ 7. ,  3.2,  4.7,  1.4],
        [ 6.4,  3.2,  4.5,  1.5],
        [ 6.9,  3.1,  4.9,  1.5],
        [ 5.5,  2.3,  4. ,  1.3],
        [ 6.5,  2.8,  4.6,  1.5],
        [ 5.7,  2.8,  4.5,  1.3],
        [ 6.3,  3.3,  4.7,  1.6],
        [ 4.9,  2.4,  3.3,  1. ],
        [ 6.6,  2.9,  4.6,  1.3],
        [ 5.2,  2.7,  3.9,  1.4],
        [ 5. ,  2. ,  3.5,  1. ],
        [ 5.9,  3. ,  4.2,  1.5],
        [ 6. ,  2.2,  4. ,  1. ],
        [ 6.1,  2.9,  4.7,  1.4],
        [ 5.6,  2.9,  3.6,  1.3],
        [ 6.7,  3.1,  4.4,  1.4],
        [ 5.6,  3. ,  4.5,  1.5],
        [ 5.8,  2.7,  4.1,  1. ],
        [ 6.2,  2.2,  4.5,  1.5],
        [ 5.6,  2.5,  3.9,  1.1],
        [ 5.9,  3.2,  4.8,  1.8],
        [ 6.1,  2.8,  4. ,  1.3],
        [ 6.3,  2.5,  4.9,  1.5],
        [ 6.1,  2.8,  4.7,  1.2],
        [ 6.4,  2.9,  4.3,  1.3],
        [ 6.6,  3. ,  4.4,  1.4],
        [ 6.8,  2.8,  4.8,  1.4],
        [ 6.7,  3. ,  5. ,  1.7],
        [ 6. ,  2.9,  4.5,  1.5],
        [ 5.7,  2.6,  3.5,  1. ],
        [ 5.5,  2.4,  3.8,  1.1],
        [ 5.5,  2.4,  3.7,  1. ],
        [ 5.8,  2.7,  3.9,  1.2],
        [ 6. ,  2.7,  5.1,  1.6],
        [ 5.4,  3. ,  4.5,  1.5],
        [ 6. ,  3.4,  4.5,  1.6],
        [ 6.7,  3.1,  4.7,  1.5],
        [ 6.3,  2.3,  4.4,  1.3],
        [ 5.6,  3. ,  4.1,  1.3],
        [ 5.5,  2.5,  4. ,  1.3],
        [ 5.5,  2.6,  4.4,  1.2],
        [ 6.1,  3. ,  4.6,  1.4],
        [ 5.8,  2.6,  4. ,  1.2],
        [ 5. ,  2.3,  3.3,  1. ],
        [ 5.6,  2.7,  4.2,  1.3],
        [ 5.7,  3. ,  4.2,  1.2],
        [ 5.7,  2.9,  4.2,  1.3],
        [ 6.2,  2.9,  4.3,  1.3],
        [ 5.1,  2.5,  3. ,  1.1],
        [ 5.7,  2.8,  4.1,  1.3],
        [ 6.3,  3.3,  6. ,  2.5],
        [ 5.8,  2.7,  5.1,  1.9],
        [ 7.1,  3. ,  5.9,  2.1],
        [ 6.3,  2.9,  5.6,  1.8],
        [ 6.5,  3. ,  5.8,  2.2],
        [ 7.6,  3. ,  6.6,  2.1],
        [ 4.9,  2.5,  4.5,  1.7],
        [ 7.3,  2.9,  6.3,  1.8],
        [ 6.7,  2.5,  5.8,  1.8],
        [ 7.2,  3.6,  6.1,  2.5],
        [ 6.5,  3.2,  5.1,  2. ],
        [ 6.4,  2.7,  5.3,  1.9],
        [ 6.8,  3. ,  5.5,  2.1],
        [ 5.7,  2.5,  5. ,  2. ],
        [ 5.8,  2.8,  5.1,  2.4],
        [ 6.4,  3.2,  5.3,  2.3],
        [ 6.5,  3. ,  5.5,  1.8],
        [ 7.7,  3.8,  6.7,  2.2],
        [ 7.7,  2.6,  6.9,  2.3],
        [ 6. ,  2.2,  5. ,  1.5],
        [ 6.9,  3.2,  5.7,  2.3],
        [ 5.6,  2.8,  4.9,  2. ],
        [ 7.7,  2.8,  6.7,  2. ],
        [ 6.3,  2.7,  4.9,  1.8],
        [ 6.7,  3.3,  5.7,  2.1],
        [ 7.2,  3.2,  6. ,  1.8],
        [ 6.2,  2.8,  4.8,  1.8],
        [ 6.1,  3. ,  4.9,  1.8],
        [ 6.4,  2.8,  5.6,  2.1],
        [ 7.2,  3. ,  5.8,  1.6],
        [ 7.4,  2.8,  6.1,  1.9],
        [ 7.9,  3.8,  6.4,  2. ],
        [ 6.4,  2.8,  5.6,  2.2],
        [ 6.3,  2.8,  5.1,  1.5],
        [ 6.1,  2.6,  5.6,  1.4],
        [ 7.7,  3. ,  6.1,  2.3],
        [ 6.3,  3.4,  5.6,  2.4],
        [ 6.4,  3.1,  5.5,  1.8],
        [ 6. ,  3. ,  4.8,  1.8],
        [ 6.9,  3.1,  5.4,  2.1],
        [ 6.7,  3.1,  5.6,  2.4],
        [ 6.9,  3.1,  5.1,  2.3],
        [ 5.8,  2.7,  5.1,  1.9],
        [ 6.8,  3.2,  5.9,  2.3],
        [ 6.7,  3.3,  5.7,  2.5],
        [ 6.7,  3. ,  5.2,  2.3],
        [ 6.3,  2.5,  5. ,  1.9],
        [ 6.5,  3. ,  5.2,  2. ],
        [ 6.2,  3.4,  5.4,  2.3],
        [ 5.9,  3. ,  5.1,  1.8]]),
 'feature_names': ['sepal length (cm)',
  'sepal width (cm)',
  'petal length (cm)',
  'petal width (cm)'],
 'target': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
 'target_names': array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], 
       dtype='<U10')}
```

Tough! I could try converting the dataset into a dataframe using pandas...

```
from pandas import *    
iris = load_iris()
df = DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
df.head()
```

[image]

which, aesthetics aside (ugly frame and bold font - subjective), is more similar to R's output, except for missing the `Species` column.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When using Jupyter Notebook, by default the dataframe will be represented as an html table.  Use `print` to get text.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names']
).assign(Species=iris['target_names'][iris['target']])

with pd.option_context('expand_frame_repr', False):
    print(df.head())

   sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm) Species
0                5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2  setosa
1                4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2  setosa
2                4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2  setosa
3                4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2  setosa
4                5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2  setosa
```

Comment: A lot of leg work... Would you need to also specify the names of the rows if  there happened to be there? See, it is not a big deal if you know the dataset, but for a quick look...

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer, realizing that there may not be any shortcut, and will come back to it to accept it if it doesn't get simplified on yours, or some other answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For similar output of R's head() can be done using Seaborne in Scikit-learn. It is mostly how it is stored in Scikit-learn and Seaborne.

```
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

print(iris.head())

   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
```